# CSS Grid generating more columns than existing

Tags: css, grid, css-grid, styled-components

I have a grid that for large screens (`@media (min-width: 800px)`) uses a grid of 12 columns with the next directive:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(12, [col-start] 1fr);
```

But for mobile devices I use instead:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, [col-start] 1fr);
```

Until here everything is fine, no clear problem. But if I add `grid-gap: 1rem;` the problem becomes obvious for the small screens since it seems that even though I specified 4 columns, it takes it as 12 columns 4 of them with 25% width and the rest with 0px so there is a bad behaviour of css.

I cannot reproduce it in a JSFiddle by the moment but I have some image of the problem.

For 12 columns on big screen:

[image: Grid for 12 columns]
[image: Computed values for 12 columns]

Applied styles: ([Other computed values](https://pastebin.com/BEqD9CJq))

```
 @media (min-width: 800px) {
   .my-grid {
     display: grid;
     padding: 2.5rem 4.875rem 0 4.875rem;
     grid-template-columns: repeat(12,[col-start] 1fr);
   }
 }
```

For 4 columns:
[image: Not good 4 columns]
[image: computed values]

Applied styles: ([Other computed values](https://pastebin.com/AYhhea7C))

```
   .my-grid {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: repeat(4,[col-start] 1fr);
     padding: 1rem;
   }
```

As you can see the computed values for the 4 columns grid has 4 columns set and the rest with 0px width...

In the element inspection there are only the lines I wrote above.

Any idea of why do we have this behaviour?

On an additional note, I am using styled-components and it is a div.

[Codepen with the error](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gqzYze)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this either ([codepen](https://codepen.io/fen1x/pen/pQpMKv)). Could you show what styles are applied to your grid-container on small screens?

Comment: Just editted the questions with the styles and also saying that I am using styled-components

Comment: Can you also show what styles are _really_ applied? You can find it in `Styles` and `Computed` tab in DevTools

Comment: just updated the question with 2 links:https://pastebin.com/BEqD9CJq and https://pastebin.com/AYhhea7C

Comment: Please post enough code in the question to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You are not posting enough code for us to solve it.

Comment: Hello, as I state, I did not have a way of reproducing this error and one of the needs was to recreate the error (then it is easier to debug), but I answered the question since I found the underneath reason for this to happen

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The element that is underneath had an span of:

`grid-column: 1 / span 12;`

[This was forcing the CSS Grid to have 12 columns.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gqzYze)

If we delete that element underneath, the CSS Grid behaves normally

Answer (score 1):

This also happens when one of your grid elements has a grid-area entry that isn't part of your grid.

```css
.about_me{
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 1.75rem 0;
}

.about_me__body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  column-gap: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 1.75rem 14% 0.75rem;
  width: 100%;
  row-gap:30px;
}

.about_me__p4 {
    grid-area: image;
}
```

```html
<div class="about_me">
    <article class="about_me__body">
        <h1 class="about_me__title">
            {{ .Description }}
        </h1>
        <div class="about_me__p1">
            {{ .Content }}
        </div>
        <div class="about_me__p2">
            {{ .Content }}
        </div>
        <div class="about_me__p3">
            
            {{ .Content }}
            
        </div>
        <div class="about_me__p4">
            
            {{ .Content }}
            
        </div>
        <div  class="about_me__p5">
            
            {{ .Content }}
            
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

Here, about_me__p4 has a grid area that doesn't exist, hence breaking the whole layout.

Comment: Hej, thanks for the addition, The question was still related to the code in the answer but it is good to document that this is a possibility too :D

Comment: Yeah, this was at the top of the search engine hits so figured I'd add on to it :)